# Asynchronous Server Sockets with Multithreading

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, asynchronous, threadpool

I want to setup a *single server* - *multiple client* system.

#### Situation

Multiple clients want to start a TCP socket connection with the server, the server accepts the connections. (The connections stay up for a long time). How should I implement the server socket part such that it can always immediately accept a new client connection in the most efficient way (meaning, spread the load over all the available cores). These are the methods I found so far:

#### Synchronous server sockets with unbound threadpool

For each client connection, the server creates a new server socket in a new thread using an unbound threadpool. The problem is that when there are many clients, there will be too many threads and the server won't be able to handle it (because of the garbage collector?)

#### Synchronous server sockets with fixed threadpool and LinkedBlockingQueue

For each client connection, the server creates a new server socket in a new thread using a fixed threadpool. When there are more clients than there are threads in the fixed threadpool, the clients have to wait until a thread becomes available again.

#### Asynchronous server sockets on single thread

For each client connection, the server creates an asynchronous server socket, since these sockets are asynchronous, they can all run on the same thread. However, then all the load on the server is distributed over 1 thread, which seems less performant, because it all runs on 1 core.

#### Asynchronous server sockets on multiple threads?

Is it possible/does it make sense, to spread these asynchronous connections over all the available cores? For example, create a thread for each core and then evenly fill these threads with the asynchronous tasks? This way it would be possible to have "unlimited" client-connections and also spread the load over all the available cores.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: The last paragraph contains my actual question

Comment: `spread these asynchronous connections over all the available cores?` My vote would be "no" it does not make sense.  You don't have enough control over which core gets the thread to run to worry about this.  It's usually considered better to make as many threads as you need (your unbounded thread pool above) and let the OS worry about which cores to assign.

Comment: @markspace creating an unbounded number of threads is really a bad idea. It would be a great DOS attack vector. Apart from that, you get a lot of context switching, uncontrolled latency etc.

Comment: @pveentjer I'll agree with that, I was speaking very loosely.  An unbounded thread pool would be impractical in many real world situations.  A fixed thread pool that could be configured externally is often a practical way to implement real world code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What we do in Hazelcast:

There is one thread responsible for accepting incoming TCP/IP connections.

And once the TCP/IP connection is accepted, it is assigned to a single thread in an array of I/O threads. So a single TCP/IP connection is handled by a single I/O thread.

The I/O threads make use of non-blocking I/O, so a single I/O thread can serve many TCP/IP connections concurrently. For more information see: https://www.baeldung.com/java-nio-selector

This design could be simplified by getting rid of the accept thread and letting each I/O thread also take of accepting by setting SO_REUSEPORT to true. This allows for different processes to listen on the same server port for accepting requests. When a TCP/IP connection is established, the OS will determine which I/O thread the TCP/IP connection gets assigned to.

You might want to have a look at the Reactor (and perhaps the Proactor) design pattern. The I/O threads I described above can be seen as a Reactor.

Comment: "So a single TCP/IP connection is handled by a single I/O thread". And on the next line you wite "so a single I/O thread can serve many TCP/IP connections concurrently". This makes no sense.

Comment: The relation isn't a 1:1, but a N:1. So a single I/O thread can process many sockets concurrently, but a socket will be processed by the same I/O thread. Without this you would end up with a thread per socket and that won't scale.

Answer (score 0):

This is largely an extension of @markspace answer, but with added focus on the why.

If your question is asking is it possible to ensure that every single request gets a unique core and is evenly split, well yes, it is possible, but if you make that an implementation requirement, you are kind of fighting the language to get a requirement met. So in short, it is possible, but no, it does not make sense.

The Java devs put a lot of time into getting concurrency and task scheduling right, which means that they wanted the tool to be a multipurpose one-size-fits-most type of tool. Obviously, not every tool is right for the job, but the goal was to limit the amount of effort you would need to spend tweaking the tool to make it right for the job. If your concern is about throughput, it would likely be to your benefit to avoid trying to force the resource allocation in a certain direction, and just request resources as you need it. Let Java focus on doing that efficiently.

In java, you can also manually allocate memory, much like C or Rust. Yes, it is possible, but the entirety point of java was to abstract all of that information away from you, via a garbage collector, so that it is one less problem you have to solve. And more specifically, it is a problem that is currently solved in a much better way than a vast majority of us would be able to do.

But back to your original question. By all means, if you think that you can perform task scheduling and thread management better than the OS (or JVM, when Loom gets here), go right ahead. But unless you have an extremely good idea on how to do that (or an extremely good reason), it likely would not be wise, let alone worth the effort. The current implementation is good enough for 99% of what you will do in your career.

Of course, if this is just to learn something (and not for a system that is being deployed to PROD), then dive in headfirst - here is the repo for most of Java's concurrency and asynchronous logic.

https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/tree/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/concurrent

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer, I'll just create a new thread for each connection

Comment: @IgnaceVau sounds good. It is also a better choice because, once Project Loom gets here, making a new thread per task will become a very cheap but powerful way to do asynchronous programming. This will make whatever software you build age well with only minor changes required.

Comment: @IgnaceVau you really don't want to create a thread per connection. You want to control the number of threads in the system.

Comment: @pveentjer Fair enough, security (DOS) can be a problem, and that would require something way more significant than just threadpools. But this is clearly someone asking the basics of concurrency and asynchronous functionality. I think simpler with adjustments in the future is a better way to approach guiding someone, no?

Comment: @davidalayachew I think it makes more sense to explain how many servers actually work instead of a very problematic approach.

Comment: @pveentjer And that's understandable. I just feel like giving solutions for problems as they come would allow each step to be better understood and better implemented.